# Tensorflow Installation Issue - missing DLL

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have pip installed tensorflow on Windows 10 along with Keras (which was installed first). When I import keras, I come up with a DLL missing error.

I have searched for it and found [this test script](https://gist.github.com/mrry/ee5dbcfdd045fa48a27d56664411d41c) which led to this output :

```
tensorflow-test.py:21: DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib; see 

the module's documentation for alternative uses
  import imp
ERROR: Failed to import the TensorFlow module.

WARNING! This script is no longer maintained!
=============================================
Since TensorFlow 1.4, the self-check has been integrated with TensorFlow itself,
and any missing DLLs will be reported when you execute the `import tensorflow`
statement. The error messages printed below refer to TensorFlow 1.3 and earlier,
and are inaccurate for later versions of TensorFlow.

- Python version is 3.7.
- The official distribution of TensorFlow for Windows requires Python version 3.5 or 3.6.

- TensorFlow is installed at: C:\Users\billy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow

- Could not load 'cudart64_80.dll'. The GPU version of TensorFlow
  requires that this DLL be installed in a directory that is named in
  your %PATH% environment variable. Download and install CUDA 8.0 from
  this URL: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit

- Could not load 'cudnn64_5.dll'. The GPU version of TensorFlow
  requires that this DLL be installed in a directory that is named in
  your %PATH% environment variable. Note that installing cuDNN is a
  separate step from installing CUDA, and it is often found in a
  different directory from the CUDA DLLs. You may install the
  necessary DLL by downloading cuDNN 5.1 from this URL:
  https://developer.nvidia.com/cudnn

- Could not find cuDNN.
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have respected all the requirements needed to install tensorflow with GPU-support.

You can find them here [under Software Requirements](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu)

If yes, make sure that your PATH variable contains you cuda's bin folder. 
The link here can help you to install all the libraries and tools needed to use TensorFlow and Keras smoothly.

Cuda from the right version and installed properly is needed for a lot of machine learning frameworks.

Gabriel

Comment: I don't want to install the GPU version, thus I've just pip installed tensorflow. It seems that only GPU-related files are missing. What can I do to simply install the CPU version?

Comment: You can go to : https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip at the end of the page you'll see all version with a link. 
Just choose the one you want and pip install <link>

Take a CPU-Only ;)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem also, what works for me was installing a package of Microsoft, that is this one:

**Microsoft Package**

https://support.microsoft.com/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads

I learnt it after several fails, but the problem was solved in the Installation Manual of Tensorflow (As the grandparents said...read the manual before use the tv, jejeje), where is writte that for Windows Tensorflow Installation is **needed this package**.

**Tensorflow Installation Web Page**

https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip?hl=es-419

And also take care of have **pip upgraded**, it is very important.

Here I put the requisites for Tensorflow Install...Good bye.

[Installation Requisites](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6tYU.png)